# How to disallow characters in JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jformattedtextfield

In NetBeans, how can I setup invalid characters for `JFormattedTextField` so that it does not allow: `|`, `[`, `]` and etc.?

**Never mind, I figured out the solution:**

```
MaskFormatter formatter = null;

        try {
            //# - Any valid number, uses Character.isDigit.
            //' - Escape character, used to escape any of the special formatting characters.
            //U - Any character (Character.isLetter). All lowercase letters are mapped to upper case.
            //L - Any character (Character.isLetter). All upper case letters are mapped to lower case.
            //A - Any character or number (Character.isLetter or Character.isDigit)
            //? - Any character (Character.isLetter).
            //* - Anything.
            //H - Any hex character (0-9, a-f or A-F).
            formatter = new MaskFormatter("******************************");
            formatter.setInvalidCharacters("|[]");
        } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
        }
```

then, on the GUI right click on the JFormattedTextField, click on Customize Code, for the dropdown box beside `myFormattedTextField = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();` select custom creation and add formatter to JFormattedTextField as following: `myFormattedTextField = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(formatter);`

Hope this will help somebody else one day.

Answer (score 1):

most confortable way is add [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) and there [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), valur to the `JFormattedTextField` could inseted (block of chars) or added char by char, I suggest to override both methods

```
insertUpdate()

changedUpdate()//Plain text components don't fire these events.
```

for inserted block of chars would be better implements `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("decision char filtering")` directly